# How to find the conjugate of a matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

To find the adjoint of a matrix first we have to find the conjugate of matrix.
for a 3X3matrix 
 \begin{bmatrix} 1&-1& 1 \\ 1&2 & 2\\1&1&2 \end{bmatrix}
some one explain me how to find the conjugate of this matrix and the adjoint of this matrix. please

Comment: Don't you just take the complex conjugate of each entry? And here, the entries are real, so...